# Updating words in javascript using variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the code I've made to change between the words when the total population reaches a certain number. The reason I did this was to be able to save the value of the `civnum` into the local storage and then use it when the user comes back to the webpage

```js
var civnum = +localStorage.getItem('civSave');
var lumberJak = 0;
var soldier = 0;
var hunter = 0;
var breeder = 0;
var population = 0;
var totalPop = lumberJak; 
var totalPop = totalPop + soldier;
var totalPop = totalPop + hunter;
var totalPop = totalPop + breeder;
var totalPop = totalPop + population;
var townOut = document.getElementById('townName');

setInterval(function() {
 if(totalPop >= 250){
  civnum = 1;
 }else if(totalPop >= 1000){
  civnum = 2;
 }else if(totalPop >= 5000){
  civnum = 3;
 }else if(totalPop >= 10000){
  civnum = 4;
 }else if(totalPop >= 100000){
  civnum = 5;
 }else if(totalPop >= 500000){
  civnum = 6;
 }else if(totalPop >= 1000000){
  civnum = 7;
 }else if(totalPop >= 10000000){
  civnum = 8;
 }else if(totalPop >= 50000000){
  civnum = 9;
 }else if(totalPop >= 100000000){
  civnum = 10;
 }else if(totalPop >= 1000000000){
  civnum = 11;
 }else if(totalPop >= 5000000000){
  civnum = 12;
 }else if(totalPop >= 10000000000){
  civnum = 13;
 }else if(totalPop >= 100000000000){
  civnum = 14;
 }else if(totalPop >= 500000000000){
  civnum = 15;
 }else if(totalPop >= 1000000000000){
  civnum = 16;
 }else if(totalPop >= 10000000000000){
  civnum = 17;
 }else if(totalPop >= 50000000000000){
  civnum = 18;
 }else if(totalPop >= 100000000000000){
  civnum = 19;
 }else if(totalPop >= 1000000000000000){
  civnum = 20;
 }else if(totalPop >= 10000000000000000){
  civnum = 21;
 }else if(totalPop >= 100000000000000000){
  civnum = 22;
 }else if(totalPop >= 1000000000000000000){
  civnum = 23;
 }else if(totalPop >= 10000000000000000000){
  civnum = 24;
 }else{
  civnum = 0;
 }
function evaluate(){
 if(civnum === 1){
  output = townOut.textContent = "Halmet";
 }else if(civnum === 2){
  townOut.textContent = "small Village";
 }else if(civnum === 3){
  townOut.textContent = "Medium Village";
 }else if(civnum === 4){
  townOut.textContent = "Large Village";
 }else if(civnum === 5){
  townOut.textContent = "Small Town";
 }else if(civnum === 6){
  townOut.textContent = "Medium Town";
 }else if(civnum === 7){
  townOut.textContent = "Large Town";
 }else if(civnum === 8){
  townOut.textContent = "Small Kingdom";
 }else if(civnum === 9){
  townOut.textContent = "Medium Kingdom";
 }else if(civnum === 10){
  townOut.textContent = "Large Kingdom";
 }else if(civnum === 11){
  townOut.textContent = "Small City";
 }else if(civnum === 12){
  townOut.textContent = "Medium City";
 }else if(civnum === 13){
  townOut.textContent = "Large City";
 }else if(civnum === 14){
  townOut.textContent = "Small Capital";
 }else if(civnum === 15){
  townOut.textContent = "Medium Capital";
 }else if(civnum === 16){
  townOut.textContent = "Large Capital";
 }else if(civnum === 17){
  townOut.textContent = "Small Country";
 }else if(civnum === 18){
  townOut.textContent = "Medium Country";
 }else if(civnum === 19){
  tonwOut.textContent = "Large Country";
 }else if(civnum === 20){
  townOut.textContent = "Continent";
 }else if(civnum === 21){
  townOut.textContent = "Planet";
 }else if(civnum === 22){
  townOut.textContent = "Solar System";
 }else if(civnum === 23){
  townOut.textContent = "Galaxy";
 }else if(civnum === 24){
  townOut.textContent = "Intergalactic Empire";
 }else{
  document.getElementById("townName").textContent= "Thorpe";
 }
}
document.getElementById("townName").textContent = evaluate();
localStorage.setItem('civSave', civnum);
}, 1);
```

```html
<p id="townName"></p>
```

Comment: Create a lookup map (by civnum) for the town names.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to reverse the order of the first function, checking for larger city sizes first. The way you have it, it will find `civnum = 1` (Halmet) for anything over 250; since the rest are `else` statements, it will never reach them. EDIT: <strike>The second function would be cleaner as a `switch`.</strike> To clean up the evaluate function, see @connexo's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but too much code for a comment. Your `function evaluate()` can be drastically shortened by making use of an array and its index (starting at 0, thats why you have to subtract 1):

```
var cities = [ "Halmet", "small Village", "Medium Village", "Large Village", "Small Town", "Medium Town", "Large Town", "Small Kingdom", "Medium Kingdom", "Large Kingdom", "Small City", "Medium City", "Large City", "Small Capital", "Medium Capital", "Large Capital", "Small Country", "Medium Country", "Large Country",  "Continent", "Planet", "Solar System", "Galaxy", "Intergalactic Empire" ];

if(civnum > 0 && civnum <= cities.length){ output = cities[civnum-1] }
else { document.getElementById("townName").textContent= "Thorpe"; }
```